# In MongoDB, how to get (a union) of all properties in documents that have multiple levels of nested/embedded documents

Tags: mongodb

In a MongoDB collection, I have a set of heterogeneous documents. The documents share some properties but not others, and I do not know beforehand what properties they share. It could be that one document has the properties A,B,D, another has the properties D,F,G,H and so forth. In addition, some may have nested documents and various levels, and we do not know this beforehand as well. So it could be that one document has a property X and X is a list of nested documents each with their own schema.

How can I get a list of the union of all properties of the documents including those embedded?

For example, for the following:

```
Document 1 has properties A,B,D

Document 2 has properties A,D,F,G,H

Document 3 has properties X,Y

where X is a list of nested documents:
Document 3.1 has properties a,g,h
Document 3.2 has properties a,g,h,i,j,k

And k is again a list of nested documents: 
Document 3.2.1 has properties bb,cc,dd 
Document 3.2.2 has properties cc,dd,ee
```

So I should get all the properties including nested ones so:

```
A,B,D,F,G,H,X,Y
And under X there should be: X.a,X.g,X.h,X.i,X.j,X.k
And under X.k there should be: X.k.bb,X.k.cc,X.k.dd,X.k.ee
```

In addition, how do I attach the first Z values available from the actual documents for each property, concatenating them into a string delimited by some character say "|". So how do I get a table or JSON file of the following format, if I'd like the first 2 values available:

```
A                ValueFromDoc1|ValueFromDoc2
B                ValueFromDoc1OnlyBecOnlyThisDocHasThisValue
D                ValueFromDoc1|ValueFromDoc2
... (truncated) ...
X.a              ValueFromDoc3.1|ValueFromDoc3.2
... (truncated) ...
X.k.cc           ValueFromDoc3.2.1|ValueFromDoc3.2.2
X.k.dd
X.k.ee
Y
```

What I am trying to achieve:
In cases where we have a heterogenous set of documents with no predefined schema, this would be very useful to understand what ALL the properties are in this Class. And sometimes the identifier used to identify the property is not sufficient for a human to understand what it means, hence I need a sample set of values to come with it.
It is very likely the case that you won't know what the schema is beforehand when you are using an auto-generated ETL, warehousing or web wrapper script.

Comment: The max level of nested documents is not known, right?
So in worst case you must assume that in fact you may have even 1000 levels deep structure?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Then in fact it sounds like recursive action... Maybe https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/ is for you? But to be honest personally I would do it in programming language after loading the elements from database.

Comment: @ZiemowitStolarczyk but what if the database has thousands, even millions of documents/records? It will exhaust the memory allocated for the programming language. if we do this document/record by document/record, it might take really long?

Comment: Well, you can use pre-processing of the data with paging + storing the results in an already calculated form for the displaying. And recalculate it from time to time. But do not know if it is the case for you.